# Create React App doesn't properly mock modules from __mocks__ directory

Tags: jestjs, mocking, create-react-app

I have a working example with Jest and mocks from `__mocks__` directory that works :

### With simple Jest setup

```json
// package.json
{
  "name": "a",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^26.6.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@octokit/rest": "^18.0.12"
  }
}
```

And then `/index.js` :

```js
const { Octokit } = require("@octokit/rest");

const octokit = new Octokit();

module.exports.foo = function() {
  return octokit.repos.listForOrg({ org: "octokit", type: "public" })
}
```

with its test (`/index.test.js`):

```js
const { foo } = require("./index.js");

test("foo should be true", async () => {
    expect(await foo()).toEqual([1,2]);
});
```

and the mock (`/__mocks__/@octokit/rest/index.js`):

```js
module.exports.Octokit = jest.fn().mockImplementation( () => ({
    repos: {
        listForOrg: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue([1,2])
    }
}) );
```

This works quite well and tests pass.

### With Create React App

However doing the same with Create React App seems to be giving me a weird result:

```json
// package.json
{
  "name": "b",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@octokit/rest": "^18.0.12",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  ...
}
```

And then `/src/foo.js`:

```js
import { Octokit } from "@octokit/rest";

const octokit = new Octokit();

module.exports.foo = function() {
  return octokit.repos.listForOrg({ org: "octokit", type: "public" })
}
```

with its test (`/src/foo.test.js`):

```js
const { foo} = require("./foo.js");

test("foo should be true", async () => {
    expect(await foo()).toEqual([1,2]);
});
```

and the very same mock (under `/src/__mocks__/@octokit/rest/index.js`):

```js
export const Octokit = jest.fn().mockImplementation( () => ({
    repos: {
        listForOrg: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue([1,2])
    }
}) );
```

This makes the test fail:

```
 FAIL  src/foo.test.js
  ✕ foo should be true (2 ms)

  ● foo should be true

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: [1, 2]
    Received: undefined

      2 |
      3 | test("foo should be true", async () => {
    > 4 |     expect(await foo()).toEqual([1,2]);
        |                         ^
      5 | });
      6 |
      7 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/foo.test.js:4:25)
```

After reading a lot it seems that I can't make `__mocks__` work inside Create React App. What's the problem?

Comment: You seem to be mixing module types (`import`/`export` vs `require`/`module.exports`), I suspect that's the source of the problem - have you tried stepping through with a debugger to see what's executed?

Comment: That seems not to fix the problem. I checked the `src/foo.test.js` to `import { foo } from "./foo.js"` and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that CRA's default Jest setup automatically resets the mocks, which removes the `mockResolvedValue` you set.

---

One way to solve this, which also gives you more control to have different values in different tests (e.g. to test error handling) and assert on what it was called *with*, is to expose the mock function from the module too:

```js
export const mockListForOrg = jest.fn();

export const Octokit = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    repos: {
        listForOrg: mockListForOrg,
    },
}));
```

Then you configure the value you want in the test, *after* Jest would have reset it:

```js
import { mockListForOrg } from "@octokit/rest";

import { foo } from "./foo";

test("foo should be true", async () => {
    mockListForOrg.mockResolvedValueOnce([1, 2]);

    expect(await foo()).toEqual([1, 2]);
});
```

---

Another option is to add the following into your `package.json` to override that configuration, per [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9935):

```json
{
  ...
  "jest": {
    "resetMocks": false
  }
}
```

This could lead to issues with mock state (calls received) being retained between tests, though, so you'll need to make sure they're getting cleared and/or reset *somewhere*.

---

Note that you generally shouldn't mock what you don't own, though - if the interface to `@octokit/rest` changes your tests will continue to pass but *your code won't work*. To avoid this issue, I would recommend either or both of:

- Moving the assertions to the transport layer, using e.g. [MSW](https://mswjs.io/) to check that the right *request* gets made; or
- Writing a simple facade that wraps `@octokit/rest`, decoupling your code from the interface you don't own, and mocking that;

along with higher-level (end-to-end) tests to make sure everything works correctly with the real GitHub API.

In fact, deleting the mocks and *writing* such a test using MSW:

```js
import { rest } from "msw";
import { setupServer } from "msw/node";

import { foo }  from "./foo";

const server = setupServer(rest.get("https://api.github.com/orgs/octokit/repos", (req, res, ctx) => {
    return res(ctx.status(200), ctx.json([1, 2]));
}));

beforeAll(() => server.listen());

afterAll(() => server.close());

test("foo should be true", async () => {
    expect(await foo()).toEqual([1, 2]);
});
```

exposes that the current assumption about what `octokit.repos.listForOrg` would return is inaccurate, because this test fails:

```
  ● foo should be true

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: [1, 2]
    Received: {"data": [1, 2], "headers": {"content-type": "application/json", "x-powered-by": "msw"}, "status": 200, "url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/octokit/repos?type=public"}

      13 | 
      14 | test("foo should be true", async () => {
    > 15 |     expect(await foo()).toEqual([1, 2]);
         |                         ^
      16 | });
      17 | 

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/foo.test.js:15:25)
```

Your implementation should actually look something more like:

```js
export async function foo() {
  const { data } = await octokit.repos.listForOrg({ org: "octokit", type: "public" });
  return data;
}
```

or:

```js
export function foo() {
  return octokit.repos.listForOrg({ org: "octokit", type: "public" }).then(({ data }) => data);
}
```

Comment: Awesome answer! Thank you!

Comment: @drinchev note I've just updated it - I think your actual implementation has a problem