# Create React App changes behaviour of jest.fn() when mocking async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, jestjs

I am confused about the below behaviour of `jest.fn()` when run from a clean CRA project created using `npx create-react-app jest-fn-behaviour`.

Example:

```
describe("jest.fn behaviour", () => {
    
    const getFunc = async () => {
        return new Promise((res) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                res("some-response");
            }, 500)
        });;
    }

    const getFuncOuterMock = jest.fn(getFunc);


    test("works fine", async () => {

        const getFuncInnerMock = jest.fn(getFunc);
        const result = await getFuncInnerMock();
        expect(result).toBe("some-response"); // passes
    })


    test("does not work", async () => {

        const result = await getFuncOuterMock();
        expect(result).toBe("some-response"); // fails - Received: undefined
    })

});
```

The above test will work as expected in a clean JavaScript project but not in a CRA project.

Can someone please explain why the second test fails? It appears to me that when mocking an async function `jest.fn()` will not work as expected when called within a non-async function (e.g. `describe` above). It will work only when called within an async function (`test` above). But why would CRA alter the behaviour in such a way?

Comment: It working well on my machine.

Comment: @hoangdv interesting. What if you added `setTimeout()` inside the promise (I've updated the question) just to make sure it's not a race condition problem?

Comment: `getTodosOuterMock` would potentially have shared state between the tests in that describe block, and is created at test discovery not test execution time; maybe that aspect went missing when you tried to cut this down?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I accept this probably isn't a realistic example. However, if I run these tests separately (comment each one in turn) I get the same result. I'm just scratching my head trying to understand why the `async - await` doesn't work for `getTodosOuterMock` function

Comment: They both pass for me, too, so there's not a lot I can say about that. Please give a [mre].

Comment: @jonrsharpe appreciate you looking into this. I have simplified the example above. The second test always fails on my machine.

Comment: That still passes for me, as I'd expect. Note that you probably don't actually _want_ a 500ms delay in a unit test, look into Jest's "fake timers" if you're testing something that's actually using setTimeout.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've only now realised that to reproduce the failing test you need to run it from a React project created using `npx create-react-app`. So it seems this issue is somehow caused by one of its dependencies. Apologies for not checking this sooner.

Comment: @trajan yep, that blew the case wide open!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason for this is, as I mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65627662/3001761), that CRA's default Jest setup includes [the following line](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/7e4949a20fc828577fb7626a3262832422f3ae3b/packages/react-scripts/scripts/utils/createJestConfig.js#L69):

```js
    resetMocks: true,
```

Per [the Jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#resetmocks-boolean), that means (emphasis mine):

> Automatically reset mock state before every test. Equivalent to
> calling `jest.resetAllMocks()` before each test. **This will lead to
> any mocks having their fake implementations removed** but does not
> restore their initial implementation.

As I pointed out in the comments, your mock is created at test *discovery* time, when Jest is locating all of the specs and calling the `describe` (but not `it`/`test`) callbacks, not at *execution* time, when it calls the spec callbacks. Therefore its mock implementation is pointless, as it's cleared before *any* test gets to run.

Instead, you have three options:

1. As you've seen, creating the mock inside the test itself works. Reconfiguring an existing  mock inside the test would also work, e.g. `getFuncOuterMock.mockImplementation(getFunc)` (or just `getFuncOuterMock.mockResolvedValue("some-response")`).
2. You could move the mock creation and/or configuration into a `beforeEach` callback; these are executed *after* all the mocks get reset:

   ```js
   describe("jest.fn behaviour", () => {
     let getFuncOuterMock;
     // or `const getFuncOuterMock = jest.fn();`

     beforeEach(() => {
       getFuncOuterMock = jest.fn(getFunc);
       // or `getFuncOuterMock.mockImplementation(getFunc);`
     });

     ...
   });
   ```
3. `resetMocks` is one of CRA's [supported keys](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#configuration) for overriding Jest configuration, so you could add:

   ```
     "jest": {
       "resetMocks": false
     },
   ```

   into your `package.json`.

   However, note that this can lead to false positive tests where you `expect(someMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(some, args)` and it passes due to an interaction with the mock in a *different* test. If you're going to disable the automatic resetting, you should *also* change the implementation to create the mock in `beforeEach` (i.e. the `let getFuncOuterMock;` example in option 2) to avoid state leaking between tests.

Note that this is nothing to do with sync vs. async, or anything other than mock lifecycle; you'd see the same behaviour with the following example in a CRA project (or a vanilla JS project with the `resetMocks: true` Jest configuration):

```
describe("the problem", () => {
  const mock = jest.fn(() => "foo");

  it("got reset before I was executed", () => {
    expect(mock()).toEqual("foo");
  });
});
```

```
  ● the problem › got reset before I was executed

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: "foo"
    Received: undefined
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot today.