# mockCallback.mock.results[0].value === undefined

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I'm trying to do a mock test fetch data from Firebase. In [Jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/26.x/mock-functions#using-a-mock-function), it is said

```js
// The return value of the first call to the function was 42
expect(mockCallback.mock.results[0].value).toBe(42);
```

But my `console.log(mockCallback.mock)` shows that `mockCallback.mock.results[0].value === undefined` with the code below. After moving the `jest.fn()` definition into the test, it is 42.

Is this behavior designed like this? If so, where can I edit the documentation to make it clearer?

```js
function forEach(items: number[], callback: CallableFunction) {
  for (let index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
    callback(items[index]);
  }
}
const mockCallback = jest.fn((x) => 42);
test("f", () => {
  // const mockCallback = jest.fn((x) => 42);
  // If mockCallback is defined here, then everything is correct
  forEach([0, 1], mockCallback);
  console.log(mockCallback.mock);
  expect(mockCallback.mock.results[0].value).toBe(42);
});
```

my jest version:

```sh
> npm view jest version
27.2.4
```

but I'm using `yarn test` in VSCode Terminal, with react version `17.0.2` and I don't have `jest` in dependencies in my `package.json`, only:

```json
{
"dependencies": {"@types/jest": "^26.0.15"}
"scripts": {"test": "react-scripts test"}
}
```

My `setupTests.ts` (in `@testing-library/jest-dom/package.json` node_modules it says `{"name": "@testing-library/jest-dom",  "version": "5.14.1",...}`):

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
```

Comment: Could not recreate (in Jest 26 or 27), once I `@ts-ignore` the unused `x` parameter that test passes for me. `mockCallback.mock.results` is `[ { type: 'return', value: 42 }, { type: 'return', value: 42 } ]`.

Comment: Thank you for editing the question. I wanted a minimal problem so I changed `x+42` to `x` and deleted `export {}`. My file `App.test.tsx` is just the code I give. Also I tried removing the `x` and `results: [ { type: 'return', value: undefined }, { type: 'return', value: undefined } ]`. I'll add version info in the question.

Comment: If you're using `react-scripts` to run the tests I'd guess it's because the mocks are cleared between tests by their default config (so when your mock function is called in the test, it _does_ return `undefined`); possible dupe of e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/65626653/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/66984091/3001761.

Comment: I add my setupTest.ts. I don't think its a dupe because we are using different methods.

Comment: Why would that matter? The point is still that the default Jest config used by `react-scripts` clears the mocks.

Comment: You mean the `react-scripts` only clears `value` in `...mockCallback.mock.calls.result` but `mockCallback.mock.calls` are kept? Although this seems wierd for me, maybe it is the reason. I'm very new to this.

Comment: No, it doesn't clear the value. It clears the _mock implementation_, `(x) => 42`, so you get the default `jest.fn` implementation (which does indeed return `undefined`, which is then correctly stored as the value).

Comment: Can you add this as a comment so I can close this question?