# CRA - Jest mock loses the mock implementation

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, create-react-app

I'm trying to use `__mocks__`.

`src/shared/state/use-some-state.ts`

```
export const useSomeState = () => {
  return { value: 6 };
}
```

which is exported from an index.ts file:

```
export * from './use-some-state`
```

And I've created a mock file like this:

`src/shared/state/__mocks__/index.ts`

```
export const useSomeState = jest.fn(() => ({value: 1}))
```

When this mock is used in a component's test the mock implementation is undefined:

`src/modules/my-component.tsx`

```
export const MyComponent = () => {
  const { value } = useSomeState();
  return <div>{value}</div>
}
```

The test for MyComponent looks like this:
`my-component.test.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import {MyComponent} from '../my-component';

jest.mock('shared/state');

describe('<MyComponent />', () => {
  let container: HTMLElement;

  beforeEach(() => {
    ({ container } = render(<MyComponent />));
  });

  it('should render correctly', () => {
    expect(container.firstChild).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

This errors because undefined can't be destructured in the `MyComponent` as the return from `useSomeState` is undefined and not `{value: 1}` as it is in the `mock`. `useSomeState` is a jest function but it's lost it's mock implementation.

If I remove the `jest.fn` from the mock and just use a function that returns `{ value: 1 }` then it works fine, so why does the mock implementation get lost.

p.s. If I import the `use-some-state.ts` into `my-component.test.tsx` file and log `useSomeState()` it works as expected, its just in `MyComponent` where it doesn't.

Comment: Are you resetting mocks at any point? If you're using CRA note that it resets mocks between tests by default: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66999030/3001761

Comment: Perfect thanks! Yeah, I'm using CRA and that was it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to jonrsharpe the answer was adding:

```
  "jest": {
    "resetMocks": false,
  }
```

to `package.json`.