# Using jest-fetch-mock and receiving null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, mocking

I'm not sure why I'm receiving null when I'm trying to 'mock' the fetch. I'm using React, along the the punkapi. I'm making a mock request using 'jest-fetch-mock'

```
fetch.mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify([{ test: "data" }]))
```

This is my fake response. I just can't understand why I'm receiving null.
The data I receive back is an object within an array, which is working.

This is my fetch request (working):

```
const random = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch("https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers/random");
    const newData = await res.json();
    return newData
    } catch (e) {
      return null
    }
  };

export { random }
```

This is my test file:

```
import { random } from "./random";
import fetch from 'jest-fetch-mock'
test("collects data", async () => {
  fetch.mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify([{ test: "data" }]))

  const data = await random()

  expect(data).toEqual([{
    test: "data"
  }])
})
```

I've also update my setupTest.js by adding this.

```
import fetchMock from 'jest-fetch-mock'

fetchMock.enableMocks()
```

---

**update**

it looks like it was returning NULL from my try catch, but my test still fails.
`Cannot read property 'json' of undefined` is my error which is coming from my random async function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like my mock request was being reset.
In my package.json I had to insert this

```
  "jest": {
    "resetMocks": false
  },
```

Apparently CRA updated the default from false to true.
[similar question / answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65627662/15231135)